# Pen not lifting from canvas

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm using easycanvas to use the apple pencil as the pen for blender. However, whenever i draw, the pen doesn't lift from the canvas. So after drawing a stroke, i lift the pen up and place it in another location, the last location of the cursor just jumps to the new location and draws an immediate straight line. Any way to fix this ?